# Custom API endpoint to create gallery for post

Tags: rest-api, gallery

I want to create a custom endpoint to upload images and create gallery as custom field for any post. I searched on codex but couldn't find a proper way to do this. 
Any suggestions or help?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/

Comment: Note that a gallery is a shortcode in standard WP, you'll need some additional glue code to turn your data into that shortcode and put it in the posts template that's separate from your endpoint. As for the custom API endpoint, look into the REST API. You can also break this question into sub-questions such as how to upload an image and create an attachment with the REST API, or how to create a gallery given a list of attachment IDs, or how to update a custom field via the REST API, how to create a REST API endpoint, etc. Bundling these altogether will severely reduce the chances of an answer